# Adjoint representaion and the normalizer of a subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider the adjoint representation $Ad:G\rightarrow Aut({\frak g})$ for the Lie group $G$ and its Lie algebra $\frak g$.
Let $H$ be a closed connected subgroup of $G$.

How to show that $\{g\in G; Ad_g({\frak h})={\frak h}\}$ is the $N_G(H)$ (i.e the normalizer of $H$ in $G$)?

Comment: I would like to see this answered as well.

Comment: This is Proposition 11 in III $\S$9.4 of Bourbaki, Lie Groups and Lie Algebras.